# What versions of Spring Cloud Stream will work with RxJava?

Tags: spring, cloud, apache-kafka, rx-java

I have built a simple Spring Boot project using Spring Cloud Stream / Kafka, mapping the inputs and outputs to RxJava Observables:

```
@StreamListener
@Output(Processor.OUTPUT)
public Observable<Response> processor(@Input(Processor.INPUT) Observable<Request> requests) {
    return requests.map(request -> {
        Response response = responseFactory().generateResponse(request);
        processContainer().process(request, response);
        return response;
    });
}
```

However it seems that I am restricted to using Camden SR1 version of Spring Cloud Dependencies.  This means that the RxJava version is stuck at 1.1.10 (later versions will not run due to RxJava library clashes).

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>Camden.SR1</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
```

I think I will need to use a later version of Spring Cloud for Zipkin Sleuth:
https://spring.io/blog/2016/02/15/distributed-tracing-with-spring-cloud-sleuth-and-spring-cloud-zipkin

**Does anyone know a later version of Spring Cloud (Brooklyn, Chelsea, Camden etc.) That will compile and run with RxJava?**

Comment: So you're saying that Stream and Sleuth require different versions of rxjava? With Sleuth you can disable the rxjava support. Then got could pick any rxjava version you want. and it should work fine for you. Also we don't enforce a rxjava version.

Comment: To clarify, I am primarily looking for the latest version of Spring Cloud Stream that would work with RxJava.  Sleuth is a secondary consideration but it will not work with the current setup.